# Not getting leading zero while retrieving from table

Tags: mysql

My table containing values in branch code column  like
 0782,kums,0763,khu 
when i select this am not getting leading zero's 
output will be
782,kums,763,khu ,
i need to get this leading zero also..
 mysql query is given below

```
SELECT * 
  FROM candidate_details  
 WHERE branch_code = '".$branch_code."'"
```

please help me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the property "zerofill" for that column.

```
ALTER TABLE candidate_details MODIFY branch_code int(5) zerofill;
```

Hope this helps.